# How to save a List<double[][]> in Unity for easy retrieval

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, matrix

I am trying to save a list of weights (List of double[][]) which was used in my Neural Network into a file. But I can't figure out how to save it because currently, my output is: "double[][] double[][]"

How do I save a list of matrices to a file?

Here is my code:

```
public void Save() {
    List<double[][]> weights = NN[neuron].GetWeights();

    Text(weights.ToString());
}


void Text(string input) {
    string path = Application.dataPath + "/text.text";

    File.WriteAllText(path, input);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it's been a little longer than I planned. But at least native (and tested)... ;-)

save method

```
void SaveToFile(string fileName, List<double[][]> weightsList)
{
  using (var w = new StreamWriter(fileName))
  {
    w.WriteLine(weightsList.Count);
    foreach (var weight2D in weightsList)
    {
      w.WriteLine(weight2D.Length);
      foreach (var weight1D in weight2D)
      {
        w.WriteLine(weight1D.Length);
        foreach (var val in weight1D)
        {
          w.WriteLine(val.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

read method

```
List<double[][]> ReadFromFile(string fileName)
{
  var output = new List<double[][]>();
  using (var r = new StreamReader(fileName))
  {
    int outputCount = int.Parse(r.ReadLine());
    for (int c = 0; c < outputCount; c++)
    {
      var weight2D = new double[int.Parse(r.ReadLine())][];
      for (int d = 0; d < weight2D.Length; d++)
      {
        weight2D[d] = new double[int.Parse(r.ReadLine())];
        for (int i = 0; i < weight2D[d].Length; i++)
        {
          weight2D[d][i] = double.Parse(r.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
      }
      output.Add(weight2D);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

using-examples:

```
public void Save()
{
  List<double[][]> weights = Cars[currentChild].GetWeights();

  SaveToFile(Application.dataPath + "/weights.txt", weights);
}

public void Load()
{
  List<double[][]> weights = ReadFromFile(Application.dataPath + "/weights.txt");

  // todo: set weights etc...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're assuming that calling `ToString` on a `List<double[][]>` outputs the *contents* of the list to a string, and probably also assume that the resulting string is *easily* parsed bask into a `List<double[][]>`. Both of those assumptions are incorrect.

> How do I save a list of matrices to a file?

There are serialization libraries (JSON, XML, binary, etc.) available that *can* serialize and deserialize such structures relatively easily, or you can write code to loop through the list and write the 2-D array in some sort of organized format, but the default implementation of `ToString` does not do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a method specific to printing your list.

```
public void Save() {
    List<double[][]> weights = Cars[currentChild].GetWeights();
    CreateTextSpecial(weights);
}


void CreateText(string input) {
    string path = Application.dataPath + "/weights.text";
    File.WriteAllText(path, input);
}

void CreateTextSpecial(List<double[][]> inputList){
    string textToAppend = "";
    for(int j=0;j<inputList.Count;j++){
        textToAppend += "[";
        for(int k=0;k<inputList[j].length;k++){
            textToAppend +="[";
            for(int l=0;l<inputList[j][k].length){
                textToAppend += inputList[j][k][l]+", "; 
            }
            textToAppend +="]\n";
        }
        textToAppend+="]\n";
    }

    string path = Application.dataPath+"/weights.text";
    File.WriteAllText(path, textToAppend);
}
```

Basically it loops through all the matrices(?) in the supplied list in prints them out in the following format:

[[0.01,0.0214,0.055,]

[0.11,0.022,0.321,0.55,0.123,]]

[[1.205,2.210,]

[0.34124,25128.250,222,2.5293,]]